# How can I merge the app dir with composer

Tags: symfony

I want to upgrade to Symfony 2.1 but I am unfamiliar with using git and the dependencies with other bundles.

I tried to download the Knp-Symfony-Version with Composer and tried to fix the versions in composer.json but there seem to be incompabilities...

Could somebody post me the steps I have to do?

Regards

EDIT:

I know cloned the master branch of symfony/symfony.

```
git clone https://github.com/symfony/symfony
```

Than I loaded the composer:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And than you can install the packages:

```
php composer.phar install
```

The only remaining question is how I download the app (and web) dir

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked better...

There is also a master branch for the symfony-standard edition: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

the doc's do the rest..